# Fake AP for Staff Security Awareness

Tags: wifi, router, spoofing

We are working on an activity to train staff about security. Is there any way to spoof the company's guest router and ask staff to provide login credentials (as public wifi does) and when they do that, we will have a list of their passwords. so, they can understand that public wifi is not secure enough.

Is there something around it?

Comment: Literally buy a new wifi router and connect it to the office guest network with the same name?

Comment: This is in many jurisdictions Highly illegal. But Hak5 does have some devices that could help you… before you do this contact A IT-Lawyer!!!

Comment: "we will have a list of their passwords" -- what do you plan to do with that PII? Do you have a legitimate need for that data? Have you checked with your legal or your data protection/information governance team to determine if you should/are allowed to collect and store that data?

Comment: Having a password, just to show them that open WIFI connections can have their credientials.

Comment: You can do that in a demo without exposing your staff so nakedly or your company to liability. You do not want their passwords and should not have or collect them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***This is a colossally bad idea.***

But the technical answer is to perform an Evil Twin attack and simply stand up a new access point with the same name and run [Evil Twin software](https://www.google.com/search?q=wifi%20evil%20twin%20github) to capture passwords.

***But here is why you should not do this:***

You are not teaching them anything except to not trust ***you***.

You are hosting a legitimate network, then setting up a fake network to capture their credentials. Why capture credentials? A simple landing page on the Evil Twin that *educates* staff on why they should not have connected to the wrong wifi access point and how to tell the difference would be better. And capturing credentials carries a number of legal risks.

Second, the security of the company access points *is up to the company*. If you want to secure your people on your networks, don't dig a pit then push them in then blame them for falling. Instead, *secure your networks*.

If you want to teach your people about the dangers of open wifi points, run a demo, make a video, ***educate*** don't entrap.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - this is a good idea.

https://shop.hak5.org/products/wifi-pineapple

But don't shame your staff - use it for training, but not to trick them normally.

It’s a good defcon-style exercise. https://www.zdnet.com/article/defcon-2007-wall-of-sheep-shame/

I don’t see the value in impersonating your guest wifi but setting up a test wifi to show people what can happen is interesting.

I also train people to never trust wifi including that provided by our company. But to trust https.

Comment: The difference is that at DEFCON, the attendees, i.e. the Sheep, are trained security professionals who expect good-natured compromise antics. The context here is staff that needs to be trained. Naming and shaming is ***never a good idea*** for staff. And certainly not without their consent. Plus the legal ramifications.

Comment: I agree but it seems off topic. I don’t think the shaming is the point of the question.

Comment: Your answer includes a link to a name-and-shame example ... "It’s a good defcon-style exercise." -- no, it is not.

Comment: Right. Whether we agree or disagree with the wall, It’s educational.

Comment: No, it most certainly is not "educational". Do not entrap. Do not name and shame. Do not confuse staff with a fake AP alongside the legitimate AP. These things do not educate. These things have the *opposite* effect of education.

Comment: It can be educational. Updated the answer to state not to shame staff.